# Find specific files in a directory through linux terminal

Tags: regex, linux, bash, scripting, operators

I have a directory x which contains n files. I need to find which of them contains the word y or z in their name by typing just one command.

```
ls *x*|*z*
ls [*x*|*z*]
```

How can I do that?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `ls *[xz]*`, or `find . -name '*[xz]*'`

Comment: Error that shows up
ls: cannot access '*[xz]*': No such file or directory

Comment: Both work in my Ubuntu 18 returning `abcx` and `abcz` but not `abcd`.

Comment: It didn't find sth.

Comment: I probably have a problem on my machine. Thank you. Going to check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use find. Specify path to your x directory, specify that you want to find only files (type-f) and list several masks for files you want with -name:

```
find /path/to/x_directory -type f -name "*y*" -name "*z*"
```